# How many elements does $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+5i)$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I don't know at all how to approach this question and how to prove anything about it. I do know that since $N(2+5i)=29$ is a prime number, then $2+5i$ is irreducible.

Comment: Hint: $(x+iy) = (a+ib)(2+5i) \iff \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}2 & -5\\ 5 & 2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix}\;$
and $\;\begin{vmatrix}2 & -5\\ 5 & 2\end{vmatrix} = 29$.

Answer (score 1):

In general $\Bbb Z[i]/(a+bi)$ has $a^2+b^2$ elements whenever $a+bi\neq 0$ by looking at $\Bbb Z[i]$ as a free $\Bbb Z$-module with basis $1,i$, and noting $(a+bi)$ is generated by $(a,b)$ and $(-b,a)$. The matrix of this subgroup is then $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$ which has determinant $a^2+b^2\neq 0$. But using the Smith normal form we know that the quotient has the form $\Bbb Z_{d_1}\times \Bbb Z_{d_2}$ where $d_1,d_2$ are the invariant factors which must be nonzero. Hence the quotient has $a^2+b^2$ elements, since elementary matrices are of determinant $1$. By carrying out the algorithm you can actually get the normal form is $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&29\end{pmatrix}$$ so the quotient is the field with $29$ elements.